# What does it mean for a tensor (e.g. $\mathrm{Ric}$) to be bounded? And also an application to Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

In Petersen, Riemannian Gometry, in the hypotesis of Myers' theorem (6.3.3.) is required that $$ \mathrm{Ric} \ge (n-1)k >0$$ for some $k>0$.

How am I supposed to read this inequality? Since $\mathrm{Ric}$ is a tensor there are for sure some vectors such that $\mathrm{Ric}(X, X)$ is arbitrary small.

I need this because it is claimed that on a connected Lie group $G$ whose Killing form $B$ is negative definite, $g=-B$ defines a complete bi-invariant Riemannian metric on $G$ (OK) such that $\mathrm{Ric}=\frac{1}{4}g$ (OK), therefore it satisfies the hypothesis of Myers' theorem and $G$ is compact. I can not understand this last implication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition should read as $\mathrm{Ric}\ge(n-1)kg$ (perhaps what you quote is a notational shorthand, I haven't checked the book), meaning that the symmetric bilinear form $\mathrm{Ric}-(n-1)kg$ is positive semi-definite (this is often written as $\mathrm{Ric}-(n-1)kg\ge0$, which is where the notation comes from). Explicitly, this means that for any tangent vector $X$, $\mathrm{Ric}(X,X)-(n-1)kg(X,X)\ge0$, or, $\mathrm{Ric}(X,X)\ge(n-1)kg(X,X)$. Now, this is clearly satisfied for the Lie group you're looking at.

Also, the strict inequality $\mathrm{Ric}>0$ denotes being positive definite, i.e. that $\mathrm{Ric}(X,X)>0$ for all $0\neq X$. This is, in general, a weaker hypothesis than $\mathrm{Ric}\ge(n-1)kg$ for some $k>0$.

Comment: I think the word "definite" has to be removed as $g \geqslant g$ is always true while $g-g=0$ is not definite.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: The word "positive" shouldn't be there at all. If $\mathrm{Ric}-(n-1)kg$ is identically zero, then it satisfies $\mathrm{Ric}-(n-1)kg \ge 0$, but you would not call it positive. The word should be "nonnegative."

Comment: I think the right word is "positive semi-definite".

Comment: @C.F.G: yes, that’s even better.

Comment: Upon popular demand, the formulation has been amended.